# How to make screenshot by unreal engine with rotation around selected object

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I want to create a data set from unreal simulation and tried to realize it on blueprint but i dont know exactly do it with 'take automation screenshot' or ' take automation screenshot at camera'.
I set my camera as object reference and it happens error.Hope someone give me some tipps for that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHed5.png)

I create a blueprint class of camera ,and set the camera as playcontroler view and it was supposed to in simulation to show the camera view and make screenshots.But in some reason it didnt worked well